# Is it safe to assume that the compiler will remove these method calls?

Tags: c++

I'm fleshing out how I want to setup a debugging logger for an application. I'd like to be able to include calls to the logger from within the codebase, but have these calls only be made when build contains environment variable `DO_LOG` (so for development purposes only, then disabled for production build). The below code demonstrates what I'm thinking:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// would be passed at compile time, but for this example define here
#ifndef DO_LOG
#define DO_LOG
#endif

namespace Logger
{
    
    void log(std::string s)
    {
#ifdef DO_LOG
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
#endif
    }
    
}

int main()
{
  Logger::log("these are words");
}
```

My reasoning for attempting this this way is to eliminate the need to wrap every call to `Logger::log` with the `#ifdef`.

What I'm questioning though is whether or not I would reliably be able to depend on the compiler  to remove (through code elimination) the call to `Logger::log("these are words")` when `DO_LOG` is not provided, since the function body would be empty.

Does this seem like it would be a safe approach to take?

Comment: If the definition is in the same TU then there’s a fair chance it will be eliminated. If it’s in a different TU, then it generally won’t, unless you’re enabling link-time optimisations.

Comment: Off-topic, but accept your strings by `const` reference for performance reasons. Without, I'm not fully sure if allocating memory (for copying the string!) is considered a visible side effect from point of view of the standard, so in worst case compiler wouldn't be allowed to optimise away at least the call of the copy constructor and destructor (but I think that would be optimised away, in case be interpreting the standard loosely).

Comment: In my opinion link-time optimization (or full program optimization) should be the norm. I would consider it a significant flaw if a compiler couldn't perform this optimization.

Comment: @KonradRudolph given that it has external linkage? It may be eliminated from the call sites in that TU but the stub will still be in the resulting binary and called by other TUs unless they do link time optimization.

Comment: @Mgetz External linkage doesn’t preclude call inlining. Yes, the empty method stub will be in the resulting binary. So what? Beyond that, what you wrote is already mentioned in my comment, isn’t it?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Being eliminated or not is not even "by chance". It's only eliminated in most recent compilers, as `std::string` (pre-C++20) wasn't `constexpr`, and compilers had gotten a very hard time fully eliminating one explicitly or implicitly created.

Comment: @Ext3h gcc 11 seems to be doing a pretty good job of removing the function call : https://godbolt.org/z/5dzqj6hea

Comment: @Ext3h Yes, I hadn’t noticed the construction of the string (`std::string_view` to the rescue …). That said, the *function call* is still eliminated, though the construction of the string sadly isn’t.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Only with `-O3`, alas. And since `-O3` provides quite a few pessimisations, most projects stick with `-O2`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph actually it can block inlining without LTO enabled even in the same TU. This is because it's possible and many implementations support replacing the definition. If the call is inlined that can't happen. Because the linker must assume that if the definition changes it should change for all call sites. So unless it is marked with the `inline` keyword then the compiler must assume it has to exist and be loadable. The linker can void this with LTO because it has more information. But the cost of constructing the string may prohibit inlining anyway due to AS-IF.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Try something longer for the string. Like `"these are very long long long long long words"`. The string is *only* successfully eliminated if the short-string optimization (content is stored in the object, not on heap) kicks in.

Comment: @Mgetz Sorry, I don’t understand that comment. Do you have an example? As it stands, the call *is* inlined (and thus eliminated) in OP’s example in the same TU. The string construction of the parameter isn’t eliminated, but that’s a separate matter (and as I’ve commented before, can be fixed trivially by replacing the type with `std::string_view`).

Comment: @Ext3h Then I guess we agree that whether or not a call to an empty function can be optimized out depends on the context. In this case, my example uses exactly the string provided by the question. My first reply was intended as a counter-example to your pre-edit comment which was a blanked statement that the optimization never occurs due to `std::string`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph think about the library case for a second and something like [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25812694) in order to support that functionality implementations (in this case GCC) cannot completely remove the call. Because I could always `LD_PRELOAD` in a version where logger actually does something without overriding the entire binary. https://godbolt.org/z/GxG5K6zKe In the executable case... yes what you've said stands... but for libraries it's not safe to assume. The larger point is... it's complicated and not obvious in many cases.

Comment: @KonradRudolph So the way it is now, by changing parameter type to `std::string_view` the call would be eliminated, BUT if I were to split this apart so that `namespace Logger` was in it's own .h file and the implementation was in it's own .cpp file, elimination would not occur because there would be two translation units?

Comment: @whitwhoa When splitting, and no LTCG/LTO is active, it can't be eliminated. With LTCG/LTO, it's still a likely candidate to be inlined and eliminated.

Comment: @Mgetz Well with the `-fPIC` argument you’re (in effect) explicitly telling the compiler not to inline these calls. But yes, that’s a valid addition to my comment.

Comment: That "duplicate" question isn't actually a duplicate. It asked about an empty body for a function with a POD only signature, while this one uses a complex type with side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your simplified example, and in specific compilers at the highest optimization levels?

Yes, it is fully eliminated. Not for the reasons you are expecting though.

`std::string("these are words")` simply happens to hit a common optimization in STL implementations: "short strings". If the string is shorter than ~24 bytes (depending on the STL implementation), it is stored inline inside the `std::string` object, and no heap allocation is created.

So when the compiler inlines your function call (that's where the optimization levels comes into play, and potentially also any form of LTCG/LTO if it isn't in the same compilation unit), it also inlines the constructor of `std::string`, and has a good chance of detecting that special case for `std::string`, which is within the complexity the compiler can handle, and both the constructor and destructor of the `std::string` get fully eliminated during optimization.

Now try again with `std::string("these are very long long long long long words")`. This time, the object is not going to be optimized away easily, even recent GCC/Clang on highest optimization levels will fail to get rid of the temporary heap allocation.

C++17 to the rescue, just avoid the `std::string` (which may copy the input just for being created), and go with `std::string_view`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

// would be passed at compile time, but for this example define here
#ifndef DO_LOG
#define DO_LOG
#endif

namespace Logger
{
    static void log(std::string_view s)
    {
#ifdef DO_LOG
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
#endif
    }
}

int main()
{
  Logger::log("these are very long long long long long words");
}
```

The main difference being that `std::string_view` never allocates anything on the heap, and being designed to be trivial to construct and destruct. Also `Logger::log` being declared `static`, such that no compiler gets the idea of skipping the inlining in a misguided assumption about having to maintain any form of interface outside the compilation unit.

Comment: Note this only applies to this example and to an executable and not a library. Libraries are their own ball of issues that get in the way.

Comment: @Mgetz Unless the library has been prepared for linking with LTCG, in which case it's a likely candidate to be eliminated again. Let's rather not go down that rabbit hole for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I wish I could but `LD_PRELOAD` gets in the way. The best and only answer to the OPs question is "it depends" LTO/LTCG doesn't block those mechanisms

Comment: @Mgetz Oh, you mean about the old gcc design-flaw of making every symbol publicly-visible by default, which in combination with `-fPIC` effectively disables any form of inlining. Forgot that there are still people not using `-fvisibility=hidden` with `-fPIC` to get rid of that.

Comment: Lots of bad tutorials out there... including here on SO.